# Finding the closest object in proxmity to the mouse Coordinates

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i've been working on a problem for a while now, which involves targeting the closest movieClip in relation to the x y coords of the mouse, I've attached a nice little acompanying graphic.

Each mc added to the stage has it's own sub-class (HotSpots) which uses Pythag to measure distance from mouse. At this stage i can determine the closest value from my Main class but can't figure out how to reference it back to the movieclip... hope this makes sense. Below are the two Classes.

[alt text http://design.camoconnell.com/images/example.jpg](http://design.camoconnell.com/images/example.jpg)

My Main Class which attachs the mcs, and monitors mouse movement and traces closest value

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var pos:Number = 50;
        var nodeArray:Array;

        public function Main(){

            nodeArray = [];

            for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {

                var hotSpot_mc:HotSpots = new HotSpots;
                hotSpot_mc.x += pos;
                hotSpot_mc.y += pos;
                addChild(hotSpot_mc);

                nodeArray.push(hotSpot_mc);

                // set some pos
                pos += 70;
            }

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,updateProxmity)
        }

        public function updateProxmity(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var tempArray:Array = new Array();

            for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                this['tf'+[i]].text = String(nodeArray[i].dist);


                tempArray.push(nodeArray[i].dist);

            }

            tempArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
            var minValue:int = tempArray[0];
            trace(minValue)
        }
    }
}
```

My HotSpots Class

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class HotSpots extends MovieClip
    {
        public var XSide:Number;
        public var YSide:Number;
        public var dist:Number = 0;

        public function HotSpots()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, textUp);
        }

        public function textUp(event:Event):void
        {
            XSide = this.x - MovieClip(root).mouseX;
            YSide = this.y - MovieClip(root).mouseY;
            dist = Math.round((Math.sqrt(XSide*XSide + YSide*YSide)));
        }   
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'reference it back to the MovieClip'? Once I know that I think there should be an easy solution to this.

Comment: Just edited my answer following your last explanation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be straight forward ...

Add a method to into the `HotSpots` so you can externally set its state :

```
public function set isClosest(value:Boolean):void
{
    // do something here, example :
    alpha = (value) ? 1 : .5;
}
```

Each time you've updated the distances you can now use the newly created method to make the HotSpots 'aware' of their respective position :

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   // sets the first hotspot to isClosest = true and the others to false ...
   (nodeArray[i] as HotSpots).isClosest = (i == 0);
}
```

**EDIT : Following your second answer, ...**

Quickly to find the closest without using `Array.sortOn` you can proceed like following. But now I think the whole code is a bit of the wrong way around (why would you have to calculate the distance from within the object, etc.).

```
// For iteration only 
var hotSpot:HotSpots;

// Keeps track of the so far closest hotSpot
var closestHotSpot:HotSpots;

// Stores the so far closest distance (to avoid recalculating each time)
var closestDistance:Number; 

// Finds out the closest
for each(hotSpot in nodeArray)
{
    if(closestHotSpot == null ||  nodeArray[i].dist < closestDistance)
    {
       closestHotSpot = hotSpot;
       closestDistance = hotSpot.dist; 
    }
}

// Applies the right state to each of the hotSpots
for each(hotSpot in nodeArray)
{
    hotSpot.isClosest = (hotSpot == closestHotSpot);
}
```

Comment: thanks again Theo for you help this is a far more logical approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i've got it working....

But i'm quite tired and believe i've most likely well over-engineered the solution.
I took your advice, thanks Theo, and added a setter method to the Hotspot Class and run a for loop that 'sets the first hotspot to isClosest = true and the others to false..'

The problem i was having was that the second Array (which i've now named 'sortArray') only held each 'HotSpots' distance from the mouse, so once i sorted the array in acsending order (from shortest dist to longest dist)i only had the distance string and nothing to reference (as in a index number) against the nodeArray. To counter this i pushed an object into the sortArray that holds the distance parameter and an index parameter. then using the sortOn() method i could sort the distance parameter then use the corrosponding index parameter to locate the appropiate mc in nodeArray.

Seems really long winded...

Main.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var pos:Number = 50;
        var nodeArray:Array;

        public function Main(){

            nodeArray = [];

            for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {

                var hotSpot_mc:HotSpots = new HotSpots;
                hotSpot_mc.x += pos;
                hotSpot_mc.y += pos;
                addChild(hotSpot_mc);

                nodeArray.push(hotSpot_mc);

                // set some pos
                pos += 70;
            }

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,updateProxmity)
        }

        public function updateProxmity(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var sortArray:Array = [];

            for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                this['tf'+[i]].text = String(nodeArray[i].dist);

                var ob:Object = {}
                ob.dist = String(nodeArray[i].dist);
                ob.arrayPos = i;

                sortArray.push(ob);

            }

            sortArray.sortOn("dist",Array.NUMERIC);
            var minValue:int = sortArray[0];

            for(var j:int = 0; j < 4; j++){
                (nodeArray[j] as HotSpots).isClosest = (j == sortArray[0].arrayPos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, it's a really bad practice here editing your questions by answering them ... Just click the EDIT link underneath your question.

Answer (score 0):

oh, 
and here's the amended HotSpots Class

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class HotSpots extends MovieClip
    {
        public var XSide:Number;
        public var YSide:Number;
        public var dist:Number = 0;

        public function HotSpots()
        {
        }

        public function textUp():void
        {
            XSide = this.x - MovieClip(root).mouseX;
            YSide = this.y - MovieClip(root).mouseY;
            dist = Math.round((Math.sqrt(XSide*XSide + YSide*YSide)));
        }   

        public function set isClosest(value:Boolean):void
        {
            var stopPos = (value) ? 2 : 1;
            this.gotoAndStop(stopPos);
        }

    }
}
```